# iPhone video screen capture for the 3GS

Tags: iphone, video-capture, iphone-3gs

With the advent of the iPhone 3GS' video capability - does anyone know if Apple bundled the ability to capture the **device** screen as a video?

**Note:** I know this question has already been asked regarding previous handset versions but I am specifically asking about the 3GS where this functionality seems more plausible.

**Update:** until I hear otherwise I am going to have to accept that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. No, it cannot be done "officially", but it can certainly be done.

Answer (score 0):

Spend some time looking this. There's nothing available to do this till yet.

Answer (score 0):

On a jailbroken iPhone, you have many options:

- Veency, an iPhone VNC server. Use a screen recorder on the computer viewing the iPhone.
- DisplayRecorder, a soon-to-be released application by "rpetrich" (in fact, a member of this site). This will produce the best videos, but will only work on the 3GS when it is released.
- There are multiple other applications found in Cydia allow for screen recording.